# Polar equation -- find area under graph using double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

What is the area of the region in the plane bounded by the curve given in polar coordinates $r = 4 + 2\cos(2\theta)$?

Could someone walk me through the conversion of polar coordinates to rectangular coordinates or how to integrate when just given a polar equation?

Comment: For polar functions, we are usually  calculating the area _enclosed_ by the curve (or some portion of it), rather than the area between the curve and a coordinate axis, or between two curves as with Cartesian coordinates.  So a double integral is usually unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the heuristic (and graphic) result:

[image]

the part of the graphic in color is close to a triangle with both sides 
of length $f(\theta)$ and angle $\delta\theta$;

its area is 
$$\frac 12
f(\theta)^2 \sin\delta\theta\simeq 
\frac 12 f(\theta)^2 \delta\theta
$$
Actually the exact formula is 
$$
A = \frac 12\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} f(\theta)^2 d\theta.
$$

A proper justification would be, from the knowledge of the Jacobian
of the polar transformation:
$$
A = \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} d\theta \int_{0}^{f(\theta)} rdr
= \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} d\theta \frac {f(\theta)^2}{2} =
\frac 12 \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} f(\theta)^2 d\theta.
$$

---

In your case, 
$$A
= \frac 12 \int_0^{2\pi}
(4+2\cos2\theta)^2 d\theta = 
2\pi \frac{16 + 0 + 2}2 =
18\pi.
$$